# Deploying Qt application using QtMultimedia in release mode

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, qt5

I am developing a Qt 5.0 dekstop application using mingw47. I use QtMultimedia in this application to record and play audio. I have tested it for debug and it works. When I try to build it for release and run the executable file, I can't play the audio file that can normally be played in debug mode. I've added the following dlls before running the executable file:

D3D_Compiler_43.dll,
icudt49.dll,
icuin49.dll,
icuuc49.dll,
libEGL.dll,
libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll,
libGLESv2.dll,
liblibmpeg2_plugin.dll,
libstdc++-6.dll,
libwinpthread-1.dll,
Qt5Core.dll,
Qt5Gui.dll,
Qt5Multimedia.dll,
Qt5Network.dll,
Qt5Widgets.dll,
Qt5Xml.dll,
plugins/platforms/(all dlls),
plugins/mediaservice/(all dlls),
plugins/playlistformats(all dlls)

What is probably wrong? Or what other dlls am I missing?

Comment: *won't work* is not an adequate problem description. Please elaborate.

Comment: sorry. I mean the application starts, but I can't play audio file that can be played in debug mode.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot play audio file? Is the *play* button missing? Does your mouse pointer magically avoid the *play* button?

Comment: The play button exists. But when I click it, the application won't play the audio file like it normally do.

Comment: How do you access the audio files ? Are their paths hardcoded in the source files or are they chosen by the user ?

Comment: The user can record using QAudioInput and play it back using QMediaPlayer. Now that I've tried the recording, the problem is not in Qt5Multimedia.dll because I still can record audio while executing the release mode. I just can't play it back using QMediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. Now my application works. It can play audio file while running the executable file.

Although not listed in depends.exe, we should add the following dlls when using QMediaPlayer:

Qt5MultimediaWidgets
Qt5OpenGL

Here is the reference: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-30172

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Use `windeployqt.exe`!  It works really well.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool

> The simplest way to use windeployqt is to add the bin directory of
>   your Qt installation (e.g. ) to the PATH variable and then
>   run:
>
> ```
> windeployqt <path-to-app-binary>
> ```

---

While you are running your application in release mode (when it is working, ran from inside Qt Creator), execute [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and point it at the application.

Make note of all the dlls that are referenced from your Qt folder.

Alternate way if you want to take more time with it:

You can figure it out by hand by trying to delete files because Windows won't let you delete a folder or a dll while it is in use. So you could go and make a back up of your Qt installation, and then run you application, make sure it has connected to all the dll's it is going to use, and then try to delete folders and files in your Qt installation.  Windows won't let you delete files that are in use by your release.

Also here is how Windows resolves dll's if you wanted to know:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18(v=vs.80).aspx

EDIT: Also, you don't need to make the folder called plugins in your exe directory.  It should be something like this:

Qt 4.x:

```
./myexe.exe
./QtCore.dll
./imageformats/qjpegd4.dll  // Note: there isn't a "plugins" folder here
```

Qt 5.x: (take from [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html))

```
The executable                   ./plugandpaint.exe
The Basic Tools plugin           ./plugins/pnp_basictools.dll
The ExtraFilters plugin          ./plugins/pnp_extrafilters.dll
The Qt Windows platform plugin   ./platforms/qwindows.dll
The Qt Core module               ./Qt5Core.dll
The Qt GUI module                ./Qt5Gui.dll
The Qt Widgets module            ./Qt5Widgets.dll
```

Also run `qDebug() << QApplication::libraryPaths()`, and make note of [paths](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#libraryPaths) that are searched for dlls on your computer.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion to delete some files and found that dsengine.dll in mediaservice folder is used by the application. I added the following code in the main function: `a.addLibraryPath("C:/somepath/release/mediaservice");` and built it again. When running the build in release mode, I could playback audio and the dsengine.dll couldn't be deleted. But when running the executable file manually, I couldn't playback audio and the dsengine.dll can be deleted. What is probably wrong when I've added the library path?

Comment: Sorry, I put some directions for Qt 4.8 deployment.  Here are the directions for Qt 5.x: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html which is very similar to Captain Oblivious's answer.  Also, go and find out what library paths you have right now.  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#libraryPaths  add to your main file: `qDebug() << QApplication::libraryPaths();` and see what prints out.

Comment: I add the codes below to the main file and test it using QMessageBox:
`QStringList libPath;`
`libPath.append("C:\\somepath\\release\\mediaservice");`
`libPath.append("C:\\somepath\\release");`
`a.setLibraryPaths(libPath);`
Both running while building in release mode and running the executable file manually give the paths I set above. So there should be no differences. But for unknown reason, dlls in mediaservice folder are not used while running the executable file because they can be deleted.

Comment: The link to the windows documentation in my answer describes the search order for a dll. Qt probably first searches that way for a dll, and then searches in its library paths.

Comment: Yes, I've read about that but I don't know what impact it has since there is no dll with the same name in windows system and the dll still not used while running the executable file. What should I do?

Comment: Figure out how to use depends.exe and then you can also look at the paths defined in your run environment in qt.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

All of the DLL's in your list that have their import libraries linked to the application will be automatically loaded by the OS. If any of them are missing you will get a dialog telling you which DLL it failed to load. The only ones that look like they might be loaded manually by the application are the **plugins**. Make sure you are telling the QT multimedia system to load the them. Also make sure you **check the error codes** returned by the multiamedia manager.

Given your recent comment that the audio plays in debug mode but not in release mode is a good indication you have put the plugin DLL's in the wrong place. When you launch your application from Explorer or the command line the `plugins` directory needs to be in the same directory as the application. Your directory structure should look something like below

```
c:\stackoverflow\myprogram.exe
c:\stackoverflow\plugins\platforms\(all dlls)
c:\stackoverflow\plugins\mediaservice\(all dlls)
c:\stackoverflow\plugins\playlistformats\(all dlls)
c:\stackoverflow\D3D_Compiler_43.dll
c:\stackoverflow\icudt49.dll

... other dll's here...

c:\stackoverflow\Qt5Network.dll
c:\stackoverflow\Qt5Widgets.dll
c:\stackoverflow\Qt5Xml.dll
```

Comment: I put all the plugins in _plugins_ folder. and i add the library path using 'qApp->addLibraryPath("plugins");'
So I have a folder _plugins_ with 3 folders inside: mediaservice,platforms,playlistformats -- each contains the same dlls as in the qt installation directory. How can I check the error codes in release mode?

Comment: It would be nice if you could include that kind of information in your question. Would eliminate a lot of the comments and prevent this from turning into an extended discussion.

Comment: sorry. now how can i check error codes when i run the executable file in release mode?

Comment: Well if you're lucky the exact same way you do in debug mode. Set a breakpoint and launch the debugger. I say lucky because the compiler may perform optimizations that prevent the debugger from showing the contents of variables.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. It seems the application can play the audio when I build for release mode. The only thing it cannot do is when I run the executable file generated from release mode.