# The camera service is missing on Windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia

Note there are [near-duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790835/qt-5-2-0-the-camera-service-is-missing) of this question but *they are not duplicates*.

Using Qt 5.4.2 I've opened the Camera Example and built it. When I run it I get the error `The camera service is missing.`

But `C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\plugins\mediaservice` I do have these files:

```
dsengine.dll
dsengined.dll
qtmedia_audioengine.dll
qtmedia_audioengined.dll
```

I haven't deployed them to the build directory, but I also haven't changed the default `qt.conf` plugins path which by default points to `C:\Qt....` so it should find them. It finds the `plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll` plugin fine and that also isn't deployed.

Does anyone have any idea why the multimedia plugin isn't being found?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found out that this is what happens when you run the camera example with no cameras plugged in. They changed the code at some point so it always tries to select a default camera. If you have none you get this message.

If you do plug in a camera it does work and you don't get the error. Unfortunately the camera API is near useless on Windows currently.