# Qt camera example does not find the laptop's webcam

Tags: c++, qt, debian, webcam

I'm using Debian Jessie and `dmesg | grep video` returns:

```
[   22.280407] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   22.790704] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Lenovo EasyCamera (13d3:5170)
[   22.796546] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

The example compiles fine but upon launch i get a dialog telling me that the camera service is missing. I'm using Qt 5.5.0. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790835/qt-5-2-0-the-camera-service-is-missing) question points to a similar issue but it's for windows. Also I've installed Qt using the installer provided at it's web site. I've tested my webcam with `Cheese` application and it works but `QCameraInfo::availableCameras()` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a definitive answer, but in my experience the dreaded "camera service is missing" comes down to exactly what the message says; for some reason the media back-end that Qt uses to get video input from a camera is broken or miss-configured in some way. In my case I had this problem in the following situations:

**1. Building Qt from source**

Qt build system **SILENTLY DISABLES FEATURES** if you don't have all the dependencies that it requires to include them in the build. Make sure to read [this official article](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) very carefully for your platform. I lost count of the times this has ruined my *<insert favourite period of time such as day/week/year here >*, and not only for the multimedia module...

**2. Missing some gstreamer packages on my Ubuntu**

I develop for Linux & Debian mostly, and on those platforms Qt depends on gstreamer backend. gstreamer is basically a plugin architecture in the core with every single feature added as plugins, and with endless possibilities of manual intervention through configuration files. See where is this is going? Clue: make sure you have all the plugins you want installed and configured properly. Here is a link to some [gstreamer tools](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+10%3A+GStreamer+tools) you can use. Same probably goes for other back-ends on other platforms.

And a pro tip in the end: Since both `Qt5.5` `gstreamer0.1` (old) and `gstreamer1.0` (new) are supported as back-ends, and since `Qt5.6` the new one is default. This will give you some room for experimenting, for example if the old does not work, you can try the new etc.

Hope this was useful!

Comment: I noticed that on a target system you furthermore need to install libqt5multimedia5-plugins